# When I run app with or without Degugging it give me an error System.ExecutionEngineException: SIGILL

Tags: xamarin.ios

When I run app with or without Degugging it give me an error as below

```
**Unhandled Exception: System.ExecutionEngineException: SIGILL
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29 
  at DicomViewerApplication.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Developer/Medsynaptic/DicomViewerApplication/DicomViewerApplication/Main.cs:18 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ExecutionEngineException: SIGILL
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29 
  at DicomViewerApplication.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Developer/Medsynaptic/DicomViewerApplication/DicomViewerApplication/Main.cs:18 **
```

but when I run the app from simulator it works properly I want to check the values that come with debugger but it give me an error

Comment: At first sight this looks like a bug in MonoTouch, I suggest you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a reproducible test case.

Comment: What is your monotouch version ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is likely solved in the latest version of Xamarin